# How to solve kernel panic at boot?

Tags: grub2, kernel

I updated my Ubuntu 16.04 and after restarting i have got this error :

```
end Kernel panic - not syncing VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-bloc(0,0)
```

Most of the commands that was used in help topics according to grubs do not work in my grub.

Comment: What specific commands did you try so far? What were the effects on the situation? How did you perform the update? Just regular update or distro update? etc.

Comment: I can't boot linux even in recovery mood. I got the same error. I updated the system through the regular system setting update.  To fix it, I wrote initrd initrd /initrd.img

Comment: Hey, I could boot to the previous version (4.4.0-71-generic) , not you?